# Valiant Knight is back..but he is in grave danger from the Evil Queen

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, knowledge, no-computers, chess

King has placed a bounty on Valiant Knight and enlisted his evil queen’s help.

Queen knows knight’s regular stops of his journey and knows he goes through all odd prime cells.

She strategically placed her self in D3 to cover all those cells. Normal chess movements apply for both the Knight and queen.

Based on the info given below, advise the Knight what cells he has to avoid so that he can journey safely.

[image]

Comment: what is an odd prime cell?

Comment: 1,3,5,7,9,11..are all odd..only 3,5,7,11 are odd primes..since there are 64 cells..you have to consider upto 63..

Comment: So... the odd prime numbered cells are all in cells that are attacked by the queen?

Comment: Yes..that is the beauty of math-chess connection...to solve this puzzle, knights moves need to be traced back or forward to get the odd prime numbers directly in line of sight of the queen

Comment: If you put down other intermediate cells also, Picture will slowly get clearer..kind of chess-sudoku

Comment: Look at both forward as well as backward moves of the Knight, then the solution becomes much easier

Comment: must the 1 be in the Queen's square (D3)? thanks

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Initial observations:

Odd primes include:

> 17 squares in total (3,5,7,11,13, 17,19,23,29,31, 37,41,43,47,53, 59,61)

Queen covers:

> 26 squares

Therefore,

> 9 squares Q covers are not odd primes, one of them is 6 in A3 (given)

My progress so far:

> [image]

Comment: You can narrow down your choices much further with given clues..lot of restricted choices to nail down the numbers

Comment: Just an observation rot13(Gur bqq ahzoref nyy unir gb or ba gur fnzr pbybe fdhner, fb lbh pna ryvzvangr fbzr bs gur ebj/pbyhza cbffvovyvgvrf)

Comment: Left side..will be lot more productive

Comment: @OmegaKrypton oh sorry, didn't see that.  I was mainly referring to rot13(lbhe frpbaq pbzzrag gung gur dhrra pbiref 26 fdhnerf, ohg gurer ner bayl 18 cbffvoyr fdhnerf sbe gur 17 bqq cevzrf.) which i'm now sure you already knew